# My nodejs query not creating user in my database with sequelize and not returning error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an API with Node.JS , express and MySQL for that I decided to use an ORM Sequelize. In short, I wanted to do this properly and avoid going through the CLI to do what I have to do.

The problem being that when I try to send a POST request from insomnia to my API it can't create a user for me, I have the impression that it doesn't understand what I'm sending to it and I I'm quite lost because I don't understand where I messed up..

Roughly I think that my problem comes from the fact that I do not know how to link the different sources of .js file between them..

I'll leave you my code maybe it's going to be obvious in any case I've already torn out a lot of hair

app.js:

```
const { urlencoded }    = require('express');
const express           = require('express');
const path              = require('path');

const userRoutes        = require('./routes/user');

const app               = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
})

app.use('/api/auth', userRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

models/index.js:

```
const db      = require('./database');
const User    = require ('./user.js');
const Vehicle = require('./vehicle');
const Service = require('./service');

(async () => {
  try {
    await db.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    await db.sync();
    // await db.sync({ alter: true, force: true});
    // console.log('All models were synchronized successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }
})()

User.belongsToMany(Vehicle, { through: 'UserVehicles' });
Vehicle.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'UserVehicles' });

module.exports = { User, Vehicle, Service };
```

models/database.js:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host:     process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect:  process.env.DB_DIALECT,
  },
);

module.exports = db;
```

models/user.js

```
const { DataTypes, Model }  = require('sequelize');
const sequelize             = require('./database.js');

const validator             = require('validator');


class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  id: {
    type:           DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement:  true,
    allowNull:      false,
    primaryKey:     true,
    unique:         true,
  },
  firstName: {
    type:           DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull:      false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type:           DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull:      false,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull:      false,
    unique:         true,
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type:           DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull:      false,
    unique:         true,
  },
  password: {
    type:         DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  birthday: {
    type:           DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull:      true,
  },
  fidelityPoint: {
    type:           DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue:   0,
  },
  group: {
    type:           DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue:   0,
    validate: {
      isInt:        true,
    },
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName:        'User',
  tableName:        'Users',
  timestamps:       true,
  updatedAt:        false,
});

module.exports = sequelize.model('User');

console.log('User ->', User === sequelize.models.User);
```

controllers/user.js:

```
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt    = require('bcrypt');
const { User } = require('../models/index');


exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {
  let regex         = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/;
  let firstName     = req.body.firstName;
  let lastName      = req.body.lastName;
  let email         = req.body.email;
  let phoneNumber   = req.body.phoneNumber;
  let password      = req.body.password;
  let birthday      = req.body.birthday;
  let fidelityPoint = req.body.fidelityPoint;
  let group         = req.body.group;

  console.log('User ->', User);

  if(email == null || phoneNumber == null || password == null || birthday == null) {
    console.log('Creditentials ->', email, phoneNumber, password, birthday);
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Champs vide' })
  }

  (async () => {
    const user = {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      email: email,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      password: password,
      birthday: null,
      fidelityPoint: fidelityPoint,
      group: group,
    }
    await User.create(user)
    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Utilisateur créé avec succès !' }))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ message: 'Impossible de créer cet utilisateur', error }))
      console.log('user instanceof User ->', user instanceof User);
    })()

  console.log('Signup User -> ', User);
}
```

If anyone can enlighten me that would be really nice of him

Comment: What error do you  get?

Comment: Hi , i have no error. In my terminal i have error {} and in Insomnia I have bad request error 400..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I finally solved my problem. I had in fact this error which does not appear from my catch in the JSON but by adding the error in the console it sent me back:

> Error: ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed!

Infact I closed the connection to the database before the work could be done so I removed the

```
finally { 
  db.close()
}
```

from my index.js and it works fine!